# Chromebit how to enter develop mode

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I had bought a [ASUS Compute Stick CHROMEBIT](http://www.amazon.cn/gp/product/B0181JTPCU?psc=1&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00)

but I don't  know how to enter develop mode,and I also can't visit google because I am in China .I have to set a proxy  in the computer stick for use.

Please tell me how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/5-tips-for-getting-the-most-from-your-asus-chromebit/) indicates that you should press the reset button, plug power back in, hit Ctrl-D and then hit enter to enable developer mode. It's similar to many Chromebooks.